# Custom Image processing(Identifying Object and coloring them)

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me out by giving suggestion and idea about how to get the area of a specific color from an image and make an overlay over that area with a different color? For example: suppose I capture a room image from my camera and I will select a color and click on any of the walls then it will change the color of the wall with a selected color.
For Reference please check: https://visualiser.asianpaints.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For picking pixels with exact color, you can take a look into [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette?hl=es) class (supported from 22 API), or try [some](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7042) third-party libraries. And then draw overlay on canvas, with bounds, generated from pixels locations. 
But to solve your walls painting task, you should also play with color threshold, that's more complicated thing, perhaps [OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) library could help you in this.